# constraint does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I want to learn it.

I have created a table to practice 'adding' and 'removing' primary key using constraints in MySQL.

syntax: `create table test1 (id_no int,name varchar(25));`

now, i wanted to add a primarykey to the existing table, and i had used a constraint so that i could remove primary key from column in future.

syntax: `alter table test1 add constraint pk_id primary key(id_no);`

when i tried to drop constraint

syntax: `alter table test1 drop constraint pk_id;`

it says:

> ERROR 3940 (HY000): Constraint 'pk_id' does not exist.

how to add constraint to my id_no column.
i had tried different methods it still says constraint does not exist
please help me

Comment: Strange, you did right. You can test here : http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in MySQL to drop the primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE test1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: it worked man (alter table test1 drop primary key;)    but when i write this syntax:ALTER TABLE test1 DROP pk_id; it says ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'pk_id'; check that column/key exists

Comment: Are you trying to drop the column after you've dropped the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
alter table 'test1' drop constraint Primary key pk_id;
```

Comment: when i exicute this query it says [ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'primary key pk_id' at line 1]